# Issue in receivng Json String in REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, callout, rest

Wrapper Class:

```
global class ApexDataContainer {
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<Purposes>purposes {get;set;}
        public class Purposes{
            @AuraEnabled
            public string purpose {get;set;}
            @AuraEnabled
            public string legalGround {get;set;}
            @AuraEnabled
            public string status {get;set;}
            @AuraEnabled
            public List<Description> description {get;set;}
            @AuraEnabled
            public string version {get;set;}
            @AuraEnabled
            public List<DataIds> dataIds {get;set;}
        }

        public class Description {
            @AuraEnabled
            public string language {get;set;}
            @AuraEnabled
            public string text {get;set;}
        }

        public class DataIds {
        }

    }
```

Callout Class:

```
public class CallDevam2 {
        //Wrapper
        public class deserializeResponse
        {
            public String id;
            public String access_token;
        }
        public CallDevam2(){
            ApexDataContainer c1 = new ApexDataContainer();
            ApexDataContainer.Purposes p1 = new ApexDataContainer.Purposes();
            ApexDataContainer.Description d1 = new ApexDataContainer.Description();
            ApexDataContainer.DataIds dIds = new ApexDataContainer.DataIds();       
            List<ApexDataContainer.Purposes> addtolist = new List<ApexDataContainer.Purposes>();
            List<ApexDataContainer.Description> addtodesc = new List<ApexDataContainer.Description>();
            List<ApexDataContainer.DataIds> addtodIds = new List<ApexDataContainer.DataIds>();
            p1.legalGround = 'MyGround';
            p1.purpose = 'purpose';
            p1.status = 'status';
            p1.version = 'version';
            addtolist.add(p1);
            d1.language = 'language';
            d1.text = 'text';
            addtodesc.add(d1);
            p1.description = addtodesc;
            p1.dataIds = addtodIds;
            c1.purposes = addtolist;
            String jsonstr = JSON.serialize(c1);
            **system.debug('@@@'+jsonstr);**

            http http1 = new Http();
            HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
            req1.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/restrequest/');
            req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token1); //The token which i had already recieved used here
            req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            req1.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
            req1.setHeader('Content-length',string.valueOf(jsonstr.length()));
            req1.setMethod('POST');
            req1.setBody(jsonstr);
            HttpResponse response1 = http1.send(req1);
            system.debug('response1:'+response1.getBody());

        }
    }
```

I have seen in the debug log before making a call out that we have the valid json but once it hits the service I get the response as

```
00:41:07:354 USER_DEBUG [51]|DEBUG|response1:[{"message":"Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: purposes at [line:1, column:14]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
```

With the same json string if I do within classes, it gets successfully parsed, do we need to do anything extra in REST call out while sending Json request as string.

The exposed service class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/restrequest/*')
global class RESTservice {
    @HttpPost
    global static String resultsDisplay(String c1){
        try{
        system.debug('1111'+c1);
        ApexDataContainer resp2 = (ApexDataContainer)JSON.deserialize(c1, ApexDataContainer.class);
        system.debug('2222'+resp2);
        return 'Connection established';
        }catch(exception e){
        system.debug('$$$$'+e.getMessage());
        return 'Connection Error';
        }
    }    
}
```

The ApexDataContainer class is excatly same in both the environments. The request gets failed in the method invoke .

Any ideas , pls ....

Comment: What is the failing JSON string?

Comment: This is the JSON debug from the above code:      USER_DEBUG [28]|DEBUG|@@@{"purposes":[{"version":"version","status":"status","purpose":"purpose","legalGround":"MyGround","description":[{"text":"text","language":"language"}],"dataIds":[]}]}

Comment: Error message: 00:41:07:354 USER_DEBUG [51]|DEBUG|response1:[{"message":"Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: purposes at [line:1, column:14]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]

Comment: I suspect, although I don't have a detailed explanation based on the internals of the JSON parser, that this is a namespace collision between the instance variable `ApexDataContainer.purposes` and the inner class `ApexDataContainer.Purposes`.

Comment: I did change the name of the class but still its the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce handles parameters to a rest service in a slightly funny way.

I'm pretty sure that your parameter is coming through like this:

```
{
  "c1": {
    "purposes": [
      {
        "version": "version",
        "status": "status",
        "purpose": "purpose",
        "legalGround": "MyGround",
        "description": [
          {
            "text": "text",
            "language": "language"
          }
        ],
        "dataIds": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

ie, c1 is treated as a `JSON` attribute.
So to get the rest of the object, you'd need to `deserializeUntyped`, grab `purposes`, `stringify` and finally `deserialize`.

Otherwise, you can skip the method param and use this technique:

```
String r = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
AuraDataContainer adc = (AuraDataContainer)JSON.deserialize(r, AuraDataContainer.class);
```

Comment: Yes, after lot of research I had used the Restcontext part yesterday because there the request body comes properly. But I am curious to know one thing as you explaned above that the entire body comes under c1, while sending the request body , I am doing.setbody which is a string and in the HTTPPOST method declartion  global static String resultsDisplay(String c1) , this is also string. so why the parsing happening on the method call itself. String to String it sould not parse anything ?

Comment: Even If i tried with this method structure it failed,                   
      @HttpPost
    global static String resultsDisplay(String c1){
        try{
        system.debug('1111'+c1);
        return 'Connection established';
        }catch(exception e){
        system.debug('$$$$'+e.getMessage());
        return 'Connection Error';
        }

Comment: Remove the param. If there is a param, the requestbody will be null. Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm?search_text=requestbody

Comment: Yeah I got that concept of restcontext, I saw just curious why it was failing for normal param where as I saw sending the body as string ...Anyway its ok as long as we have workarounds. Thanks for our help.